# Python, how to optimize this code

Tags: python, performance, numpy, cython

I tried to optimize the code below but I cannot figure out how to improve computation speed. I tried Cthon but the performance is like in python.

Is it possible to improve the performance without rewrite everything in C/C++?

Thanks for any help

```
import numpy as np

heightSequence = 400
widthSequence = 400
nHeights = 80

DOF = np.zeros((heightSequence, widthSequence), dtype = np.float64)
contrast = np.float64(np.random.rand(heightSequence, widthSequence, nHeights))

initDOF = np.zeros([heightSequence, widthSequence], dtype = np.float64)
initContrast = np.zeros([heightSequence, widthSequence, nHeights], dtype = np.float64)
initHeight = np.float64(np.r_[0:nHeights:1.0])
initPixelContrast = np.array(([0 for ii in range(nHeights)]), dtype = np.float64)


# for each row
for row in range(heightSequence):
    # for each col
    for col in range(widthSequence):

        # initialize variables            
        height = initHeight # array ndim = 1
        c = initPixelContrast # array ndim = 1

        # for each height            
        for indexHeight in range(0, nHeights):
            # get contrast profile for current pixel
            tempC = contrast[:, :, indexHeight]
            c[indexHeight] = tempC[row, col]

        # save original contrast            
        # originalC = c
        # originalHeight = height                

        # remove profile before maximum and after minumum contrast
        idxMaxContrast = np.argmax(c)
        c = c[idxMaxContrast:]
        height = height[idxMaxContrast:]

        idxMinContrast = np.argmin(c) + 1
        c = c[0:idxMinContrast]
        height = height[0:idxMinContrast]              

        # remove some refraction
        if (len(c) <= 1) | (np.max(c) <= 0):
            DOF[row, col] = 0                  

        else:

            # linear fitting of profile contrast                                             
            P = np.polyfit(height, c, 1)
            m = P[0]
            q = P[1]

            # remove some refraction               
            if m >= 0:
                DOF[row, col] = 0

            else:
                DOF[row, col] = -q / m

    print 'row=%i/%i' %(row, heightSequence)

# set range of DOF
DOF[DOF < 0] = 0
DOF[DOF > nHeights] = 0
```

Comment: What's the data? Can you add some for reference so that this piece of code runs by itself? You could generate some arrays of the right shape with `np.random.rand` , for example.

Comment: If you **do not** want C or C++ suggestions then do not add such tags.

Comment: The data is a stack of 80 images... I will update the code to run by itself but I need some time to test if everything is OK xD this is only a small portion of my whole algorithm where is the bottleneck

Comment: That would be good - otherwise it's all guesswork on the part of anyone trying to answer your question and that's not much use to you or us...

Comment: [*Possibly helpful ...*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4299378/23771)

Comment: I updated the code, now it is running by itself :) on i7 CPU it is very slow... and this is only for one stack of images, usually I have 260 stacks and the resolution is much greater than in this demo xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By looking at the code it seems that you can get rid of the two outer loops completely, converting the code to a *vectorised* form. However, the `np.polyfit` call must then be replaced by some other expression, but the coefficients for a linear fit are easy to find, also in vectorised form. The last `if-else` can then be turned into a `np.where` call.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will try to follow your advice... but I am pretty new in python, anyway, I will try it :)

Comment: It's the same advice that applies to e.g. using Matlab: try to get rid of the loops (at least most of the time)

Comment: OK, I finished to implement the part about polyfit algorithm (I implemented these formulas http://www.codecogs.com/code/maths/approximation/regression/linear.php in python in very efficient way without the "for row" and "for col" loops). My last problem is to optimize the statements with argmax(c) and argmin(c). Have you an idea how to do this computation outside the loops?

Comment: Just specify the `axis` along which you want to operate. If you don't specify an `axis`, `numpy` operates on the flattened array (i.e. the global minimum and maximum). In your case, `axis` would be probably be `2`.

Comment: Dear Michael Wild, thanks a lot :) it's working like a charm :) now I can analyze one experiment in less than 1 minute, I really appreciate your help